# Unable to center Bootstrap list-group container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hope you're doing well today.

So I'm working on a sidebar with Bootstrap's list-group and I want to apply a specific width so that it aligns with the two other elements (top and bottom). After I used 300px as the width, the container aligns to the left as shown in the picture below. But I want it to be at the center.

I tried `align-items: center` as the container is using `flex-direction: column` but then it becomes too thin and doesn't take 300px as the width although it moves to the center.

I also tried using `display: inline` and used `margin: 0 auto` but its unresponsive.

This is how it looks now after I used `max-width: 300px`:

[image]

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">

      <div class="ad-space">
             <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" class="">
      </div>

      <div class="list-group recent-articles-container my-5">
              <div class="card-header">
                     <h2>Recent Articles</h2>
              </div>

              <div>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Lorem Ipsum</a>    
              </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ad-space">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" class="">
      </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-group {
    max-width: 300px !important;
}
```

How can I move it to the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to use `width: 100%` in `list-group`.

Here's the css:

```
.list-group {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 300px !important;
}
```